# Assigning to rvalue for === equality in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My code is quite simple:

```
<b-button
    v-for="t in tags" :key="t"
    :to="{ name: 'tag', params: { tag: t } }"
    :pressed.sync="t === tag"
>#{{t}}</b-button>

props: {
  tag: String,
},
```

But it fails:

```
 SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue (1:341)
```

It works when I remove this comparison:

```
:pressed.sync="t === tag"
```

If there was `"t = tag"` I would understand. Even Idea thinks my code is fine and it complains when I use `"t == tag"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.sync` modifier.

> [**`.sync` Modifier**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)
>
> Note that `v-bind` with the `.sync` modifier does not work with expressions (e.g. `v-bind:title.sync="doc.title + '!'"` is invalid). Instead, you must only provide the name of the property you want to bind, similar to `v-model`.

The button component is trying to write the *pressed* state back to the expression you provided. It's like trying

```js
(a === b) = c
```

which throws an invalid assignment error.

Comment: good gotcha, thank you. I have copied this sequence blindly from the documentation.